# Unable to get element with id from a URL using HtmlUnit in Java

Tags: java, htmlunit

Unable to get element with `id="parcelMailingAddressResult"` from `https://www.mohavecounty.us/ContentPage.aspx?id=111&cid=869&parcel=10272001` using `HTMLUnit` in `Java`

If you go to above URL , you will see that there is a mailing address. A DOM inspection of the website shows that address has the above mentioned ID. I have been trying for several days to get that mailing address using my Java/HTMLUnit, and none of my tries worked.
Below are three methods that I tried within the same code.

```
System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal");
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);           
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("handleRefresh");
}
});
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.mohavecounty.us/ContentPage.aspx?id=111&cid=869&parcel=10272001"); 
DomElement ownerAddresses = page.getElementById("parcelMailingAddressResult");
NodeList nodes = page.getElementsByTagName("parcelMailingAddressResult");
final HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getByXPath("//div[@class='container-fluid row']").get(0);
```

I expected the variables `ownderAddresses` and nodes to contain information that includes the owner's address. I expect `div` to contain some other information and, once I changed `get(0)` to `get(<someHigherInteger>)`, to contain also information about the owner's address.

**Instead:**

1. `ownerAddresses = null` (after execution of ownerAddress = ...)
2. nodes is of size 0 (after execution of nodes = ...)
3. `final HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getByXPath("//div[@class='container-fluid row']").get(0);`
   after about 13 seconds, throws the following exception:

**Exception:**
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`.

which means that `(HtmlDivision) page.getByXPath("//div[@class='container-fluid row']")` was of length 0.

Comment: Problems : 1. The way you asked the question is little confusing. (Consider to edit the question). 2. The URL is not working for me (May be for your java program too). 3. Have you debug `HtmlPage page` (I guess it won't be populated and hence the timeout exception).

Comment: 1) Please tell me what part of the question you believe to be confusing. 2) I just checked and the URL worked for me. Maybe you tried it at a time when the website was down. I ran the code at a time when the website was up. It's also up as of the typing of the present comment. 3) I did run the program (most of which was not shown in my question) through the debugger, and there was plenty of stuff in page (the HtmlPage). I just was unable to get to the parts of the page that I need, which are inside several nested divs.

Comment: I figured part of what was wrong. I should NOT have written "webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);" in the code. I commented that out. Now, after execution of OwnerAddresses = ....., OwnerAddresses.toString() is equal to HtmlHeading5[<h5 class="col-md9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" id="parcelMailingAddressResult">]. THAT is the heading that has the owner's address, as shown by the following "Inspect Element" of Firefox: <h5 class="col-md9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" id="parcelMailingAddressResult">3714 LINCOLNWOOD DR, SANTA BARBARA, CA 931101556</h5> ..... Now, how do I get the address ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem technically **solved**. Here is the new code:

```
System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal");
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
    public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("handleRefresh");
}
});
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.mohavecounty.us/ContentPage.aspx?id=111&cid=869&parcel=10272001"); 
HtmlElement ownerAddressElement = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("parcelMailingAddressResult");
String ownerAddress = ownerAddressElement.asText();
```

I say "technically", because it takes the above code about an hour on my virtual machine to get the ownerAddress. In practice, it makes my code very hard to use. I suspect the following: when you go to `https://www.mohavecounty.us/ContentPage.aspx?id=111&cid=869&parcel=10272001` , it takes the page only a few seconds to load. But the blue "Search" button shows the busy signal even after an hour and half. I suspect the JavaScript of the page has entered into some infinite loop which makes webClient believes that the page is still loading, until it loses patience after an hour.

I would like to cut that time from an hour to less than 30 minutes. But that's another question, which I will ask as a separate question at Stack Overflow.